# Change linear layout to another linear layout onclick

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I have a linear layout that is called in a simple view and I want it to expand and change to a completely different layout on click but I can't change it in the on click because it is final

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final LinearLayout linearView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_layout, null);

    linearView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               //Change linearview to R.layout.linear_layout2

        }
    });
```

Comment: Remove "final" modifier?

Answer (score 0):

Declare linearView as a member variable of the class it's used in.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    //...//

    public void initLayout() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_layout, null);

        mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //Change mLinearLayout to R.layout.linear_layout2

            }
        });
    }
}
```